# How to use $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']

Tags: php

Is there any difference between typing:

```
<?php echo $_SERVER[REQUEST_URI] ?>
```

or

```
<?php echo $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'] ?>
```

or

```
<?php echo $_SERVER["REQUEST_URI"] ?>
```

?

They all work... I use the first one.
Maybe one is faster than the other?

Comment: Just a friendly advice - Ask questions with a title which has the form of a question in the future. It makes them easier to grasp quickly, which is important when there are so many questions around.

Comment: My 2c (not a mod): This is more of a general question of how to access array elements in PHP arrays than a question of how to use REQUEST_URI. I would rephrase this and probably close as duplicate. Should probably also be closed as "too trivial" or something like that. Also, the first example will propably break with latest PHP version and tools like php-cs-fixer and phpstan can be used to check and clean up code which make the question obsolete and outdated. Also, the title is misleading. It is not really a question about how to actually use REQUEST_URI but how to access an array.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

**Without quotes PHP interprets the `REQUEST_URI` as a constant** but corrects your typo error if there is no such constant and interprets it as string.

When [`error_reporting`](http://docs.php.net/manual/en/errorfunc.configuration.php#ini.error-reporting) includes [`E_NOTICE`](http://docs.php.net/manual/en/errorfunc.constants.php), you would probably get an error such as:

> Notice: Use of undefined constant REQUEST_URI - assumed 'REQUEST_URI' in *<file path>* on line *<line number>*

But if there is a constant with this name, PHP will use the constant’s value instead. (See also [Array do's and don'ts](http://docs.php.net/manual/en/language.types.array.php#language.types.array.donts))

**So always use quotes when you mean a string.** Otherwise it can have unwanted side effects.

And for the difference of single and double quoted strings, see the [PHP manual about strings](http://docs.php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php).

Answer (score 3):

The first one is wrong - you're actually looking for a constant `REQUEST_URI` that doesn't exist.  This will generate a notice-level warning.

There's no difference between the other two.

Comment: Wouldn't the third be slower than the second, because php will be looking for variable names inside the string?

Comment: That’s absolutely negligible. You should better optimize other things than this.

Comment: Still a useful standard to follow. Only use double quotes when there are variables to be parsed (or occasionally if you're too lazy to escape apostrophes).

Comment: Yes, I know it's negligible. But saying "There's no difference between the other two." isn't really true, and when you are dealing with bigger strings etc. it could be worthwhile to consider

Answer (score 3):

There is a difference between single and double quotes in PHP string handling. A string enclosed in double quotes will be evaluated for embedded variables and escape characters (e.g. \n); a string enclosed in single quotes won't (or not as much).

So, for example,

```
$hello = "world";

echo "Hello $hello!\n";
echo 'Hello $hello!\n';
echo 'Done';
```

will output

> Hello world!
> Hello $hello!\nDone

In situations where you have no escape characters or embedded variables, it is slightly more efficient to use single quotes as it requires less processing of the string by the runtime. However, many people (me included) prefer to use double quotes for all strings to save confusion.

Answer (score 1):

As a caveat to Gumbo's answer the third representation - double quotes - actually makes PHP look for variables inside that string. Thus that method might be a little slower (although in a string of 11 characters it'll be negligible - it's better practice not to make PHP do that however).

Answer (score 1):

When PHP comes across plain strings being used as array keys it checks if there is a constant with that name and if there isn't it defaults it back to an array key. Therefore, not using quote marks causes a slight performance hit and there is a possibility that the result will not be what you expect.

Answer (score -1):

```
$_SERVER[REQUEST_URI]
```

is syntatically incorrect and AFAIK will not run on a default installation of PHP5. The array index is a string so it needs to be passed on strings. I know PHP4 converted undefined constants to strings inside the square brackets but it's still not good practice.

EDIT: Well unless you define a constant called REQUEST_URI, which you haven't in your example script.

```
$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']
```

is the standard method and what you should be using.

```
$_SERVER["REQUEST_URI"]
```

also works and while not wrong is slightly more work for the PHP interpreter so unless you need to parse it for variables should not be used. (and if you need to do so, you need to rethink that part of your program.

Comment: The first example is syntactically an semantically correct if there is a constant with that name.

Comment: Indeed it is. However this script consists of a whole three lines, none of which look like

   define("REQUEST_URI", $_SERVER['REQUEST_URL']);